# Creating a task from another task

Tags: freertos

I am trying to create a task from another task. I tried few sources but am not getting any better results. I tried the example given on https://www.instructables.com/id/FreeRTOS-With-Arduino-08-Creating-a-Task-From-Othe/. In the serial monitor it only displays "In Setup function Task3 Running, Creating Task2 and Task4". With reference to [creating task inside other task in freertos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191990/creating-task-inside-other-task-in-freertos)
I tried checking the value returned by xTaskCreate and printing the return value but that value doesn't print. Can someone help on this? What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with project specifics, or instructions on other website, but yes it is perfectly fine to [create one task from another](http://www.freertos.org/a00125.html).  That is what the strangely named ['death' tasks](https://sourceforge.net/p/freertos/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/FreeRTOS/Demo/Common/Minimal/death.c) demonstrate - one of the oldest (very first) standard demo tasks that shipped with FreeRTOS and runs on all the platforms [we support ourselves].